# uint.MaxValue in .NET

Tags: .net

```
uint x = uint.MaxValue - 100;
```

The above line causes visual studio to report "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode"

I'm obviously missing something. Any ideas what?

Comment: Do you still get this error when you actually compile your code? See the output window instead of the error list.

Comment: No, if I run the application it runs fine. Once I stop the applicationa and return to VS the error is not in the list. It only reappears after a code edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this error is being reported by the C# frontend used by the VS refactoring tool. When you go ahead and compile it using the actual compiler the error disappears!

Comment: That would explain why it seems happy sometimes and then (often after a pause) the "error" pops up.

Comment: Well, most likely the VS refactoring compiler is a specialized compiler built for speed and code transformation hence could be somewhat different from the main compiler.

Comment: Ok one more thing the VS refactoring compiler is able to compile smaller subsets of all the files present in a project which might suggest its able to work on incomplete information upto a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

It may be implicity converting the uint.MaxValue to **signed** because you are subtracting a constant which is implicity signed.  Try:

```
uint x = uint.MaxValue - 100U;
```

Comment: This does not work either. Seems to be a bug in the refactoring compiler.